# No Cookies in Headers using Axios withCredentials: true

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I am using ReactJS and ExpressJS with jwt authenticate. In my server, I have config for cors like this

```
const corsOptions = {
  //To allow requests from client
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Set-Cookie'],
};
```

In my client, I send request to the Server like this

```
export function createNewRequest(data, callback) {
 axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/requests`, data,
     {
         withCredentials: true
     }).then(res => {
         callback(res.data);
     })
     .catch(err => {
        if (err.response) {
            if (err.response.status === 403 || err.response.status === 401) {
                getToken(createNewRequest(data, callback));
            } else {
                callback(err.response.data);
            }
        }
     })
}
```

In my local environment, I test and every thing run fine. But when i deploy my server, then i try to send request from my local client to the server. The server doesn't receive cookies in headers.

I have tried setting origins like this

```
const corsOptions = {
 //To allow requests from client
 origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
 credentials: true,
 methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
 allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Set-Cookie'],
};
```

And tried to set default withCredentials

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

But none of these work. Can anyone explain to me what i did wrong and help me solve this

Answer (score -1):

Try to allow `app.use(cors());` like this without option(to allow everything).
example of code:

```js
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ origin: "https://famegoal.com/" }));

app.use("/function", couponRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.qvs4c.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

    app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
      console.log("Node app is running on port", app.get("port"));
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

That's not safe, but it's a great solution.

Comment: I tried this first and the request is blocked due to CORS policy so i need to specify the corsOptions

Answer (score -1):

set the following middleware in your app.js as follows

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
  Accept'
  )
  next()
});
```

and in reactjs use `withCredentials: true`